# TFS 2015 and VS 2013 build definitions

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs-2015

I use VS 2013 because of Biztalk 2013 developments. Currently we use TFS 2015 with a build agent from TFS 2013 for automatic builds.
We need to migrate all to TFS 2015 and we want to migrate the xaml approach of build definitions to vNext.
Thing is, because of biztalk version, we need to keep using VS2013 and in the view Team Explorer under Builds I cannot see the build definitions created as vNext.
I've searched for plugins/extensions and updates or even some documentation but I couldn't really find anything related to this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Daniel said, the vNext build system is entirely web-based and Visual Studio 2013 does not show non-XAML build definitions.

So, you can use below workarounds to see the list of existing build definition (However you can only edit the build definitions via the web portal for vNext build definitions):

1. Using the web UI : `http://server:8080/tfs/Collection/Project/_build`
2. Install Visual Studio 2015+ or at leat install [Team Explorer
   2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/04/05/team-explorer-for-tfs-2017/) standalone
3. Get the build definition list with the REST API: [Get a list of
   build definitions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#get-a-list-of-build-definitions)
4. Create a Console app and use the BuildHttpClient to make requests,refer to below sample:

---

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;

namespace GetBuildDefinition
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tfsUrl = "http://server:8080/tfs/Collection";
            var buildClient = new BuildHttpClient(new Uri(tfsUrl), new VssAadCredential());
            var definitions = buildClient.GetDefinitionsAsync(project: "ProjectNameHere");

            foreach (var definition in definitions.Result)  
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", definition.Id, definition.Name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Andy Li-MSFT, sorry for the time. Thank you for the suggestion. I'll need to check if it is viable to use it.

Answer (score 2):

VS 2013 and lower versions do not show vNext builds and build definitions, you need VS 2015 and later for that. As an option, if you want to keep an eye on the build status, you can try CatLight build notification tool (check below 1st link) that works independently of Visual Studio and supports vNext builds. Else, Web version is pretty awesome to use and handle.

Incase you have any other queries regarding TFS builds, please let know.

Also, below Microsoft links could be helpful.

1. [vNext builds are not visible in VS Team Explorer pane](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a14779ab-3c32-47ca-bb64-eaa91873374d/vnext-builds-are-not-visible-in-vs-team-explorer-pane-and-build-notifications-application?forum=TFService)
2. [VS Compatibility with TFS versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

The build system in TFS 2015+ is entirely web-based. Even VS2015+ will just bounce you to the web to do anything with the builds.

So the answer is, "Get used to using the web UI."

Comment: Hi @Daniel Mann, but I was wondering if I could at least be able to see the list of existing build definition on VS 2013.

Comment: The answer is no. You can run Team Explorer 2017 side-by-side though...

Answer (score -1):

If you have the build definitions in place and you are connected to the correct tfs workspace project, then you should see the list definition on your vs panel, the only thing that you can't do is edit the build definition. As @DanielMann said, from that point on everything is web-based, what you can do is queue a new build and see the list. You don't need any plugin for that

Comment: This answer is wrong. Visual Studio 2013 does not show non-XAML builds.

Comment: @DanielMann you are right, my mistake, I am using the VS2017, my answer was base on that